# String sub not working correctly

Tags: string, lua, substring, coronasdk

I've got yet another question about lua. I've created a method to calculate the total amount of some prices. The prices are in this format: £500. So to convert them to numbers I'm using string:sub() and tonumber(), but I'm getting some weird results. Here is my code:`

```
function functions.calculateTotalAmount()
print("calculating total amount")
saveData.totalAmount = 0
print("There are " .. #saveData.amounts .. " in the amount file")
for i=1, #saveData.names do
    print("SaveData.amounts[" .. i .. "] original = " .. saveData.amounts[i])
    print("SaveData.amounts[" .. i .. "]  after sub= " .. saveData.amounts[i]:sub(2))
    print("totalAmount: " .. saveData.totalAmount)
    if saveData.income[i] then
        saveData.totalAmount = saveData.totalAmount + tonumber(saveData.amounts[i]:sub(2))
    else
        saveData.totalAmount = saveData.totalAmount - tonumber(saveData.amounts[i]:sub(2))
    end
end
totalAmountStr.text = saveData.totalAmount .. " " .. currencyFull
loadsave.saveTable(saveData, "payMeBackTable.json")
```

end

I printed out some info in the for loop to determine the problem and this is what is being printed for the first 2 print statements in the for loop:

16:03:51.452  SaveData.amounts[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tDQn.png) original = ¥201

16:03:51.452  SaveData.amounts[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tDQn.png)  after sub=  201

It looks fine here in stackoverflow but for the the ¥ is actually not gone in my log, instead it is replaced with a weird rectangle symbol. There will be a picture of the printed text attached to this post.
Does anyone see what is going on here?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `sub` in this case as the `¥` sign is likely a multi-byte sequence (depending on the encoding), so using `sub(2)` you are cutting it in the middle instead of removing it.

Use `gsub("[^%d%.]+","")` instead to remove all non-numeric parts.

Comment: This worked for me! I assumed the sub function would work with these character because it did seem to work with the dollar sign. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`string.sub()` works on the *bytes* of a string, not on its *chars*. There is a difference when the string contains Unicode text.

If the number is at the end of the string, extract it with

```
amount = tonumber(saveData.amounts[i]:match("%d+$"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Lua strings are strings of *bytes*, not strings of *characters*.  ASCII characters are 1 byte long, but most other characters consume multiple bytes, so using `string.sub()` isn't going to work.

There are several standards for converting between *bytes* and *characters* (or *code points*), but by far the most common on the web is UTF-8.  If you are using Lua 5.3 or greater, you can use new [built-in functions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.5) for performing UTF-8 manipulation.  For example, to take a substring of a UTF-8 string, you can do:

```
-- Simple version without bounds-checking.
function utf8_sub1(s, start_char_idx, end_char_idx)
  start_byte_idx = utf8.offset(s, start_char_idx)
  end_byte_idx = utf8.offset(s, end_char_idx + 1) - 1
  return string.sub(s, start_byte_idx, end_byte_idx)
end

-- More robust version with bounds-checking.
function utf8_sub2(s, start_char_idx, end_char_idx)
  start_byte_idx = utf8.offset(s, start_char_idx)
  end_byte_idx = utf8.offset(s, end_char_idx + 1)
  if start_byte_idx == nil then
    start_byte_idx = 1
  end
  if end_byte_idx == nil then
    end_byte_idx = -1
  else
    end_byte_idx = end_byte_idx - 1
  end
  return string.sub(s, start_byte_idx, end_byte_idx)
end

s = "¥201"

print(string.sub(s, 2, 4)) -- an invalid byte sequence
print(utf8_sub1(s, 2, 4)) -- "201"
print(utf8_sub2(s, 2, 4)) -- "201"
print(utf8_sub1(s, 2, 5)) -- throws an error
```

If you don't have Lua 5.3, you can use a UTF-8 library like [this one](https://luapower.com/utf8) instead to achieve the same functionality.